# Functions That Also Satisfy Binomial Distribution Recurrence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Consider a function $f(k,n,p)$ that satisfies the following recurrence:

$$
f(k,n,p) = p\cdot f(k-1, n-1, p) + (1-p) \cdot f(k, n-1, p)\,.
$$

This is of course the probability of $k$ successes from $n$ trials, easily satisfied by: $$f(k,n,p) = {n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\,,$$ but I was wondering:

Are there other examples of functions that satisfy this recurrence relation, for $k,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $p \in \mathbb{R^+}$?

Comment: I don't know much about recurrence relations, but is there some sort of uniqueness statement/theorem for them (which I would imagine is contingent upon initial conditions being given)? If so, I would imagine that this is probably the unique solution. Also, I'm going to remove the probability theory tag, since this isn't really a probability question, rather one about recurrence relations only with an example that has applications in probability.